# Java + Spring Serialize and deserialize a Map<Enum, String>

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, jackson

i'm having this issue when I try to deserialize and serialize a Map<EventResponseEnum, String>.
I tried to create a Serializer configuration, I annotated with @JsonCreator, @JsonValue, @JsonFormat(shape=Object) and nothing worked.

When I create this event, the response comes right: {"organizer": "YES": "Name"}.
This problem is only when I try to retrieve the information of the database.

`"Could not write JSON: java.lang.String incompatible with java.lang.Enum; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.lang.String incompatible with java.lang.Enum (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->br.com.murilo.agenda.dto.response.EventResponse[\"organizerResponse\"])"`

Follow the enum and response classes:

```
@Document(collection = "event")
public enum EventResponseEnum {

    YES("Yes"),
    NO("No"),
    MAYBE("Maybe");

    private String response;
    private static Map<String, EventResponseEnum> byResponse = new HashMap<>();

    EventResponseEnum(final String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    static {
        byResponse.putAll(
                Stream.of(
                        values())
                        .collect(
                                Collectors.toMap(
                                        EventResponseEnum::getResponse,
                                        Function.identity())));
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public static Map<String, EventResponseEnum> getByResponse() {
        return byResponse;
    }
}
```

```
public class EventResponse {

    private String id;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime initialDateTime;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime finalDateTime;
    private String eventColor;
    private Map<EventResponseEnum, String> organizerResponse;
    private Map<EventResponseEnum, List<String>> guestResponse;

    public EventResponse(){
        this.organizerResponse = new HashMap<>();
        this.guestResponse = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public EventResponse(final String id,
                         final LocalDateTime initialDateTime,
                         final LocalDateTime finalDateTime,
                         final String eventColor,
                         final Map<EventResponseEnum, String> organizerResponse,
                         final Map<EventResponseEnum, List<String>> guestResponse) {
        this.id = id;
        this.initialDateTime = initialDateTime;
        this.finalDateTime = finalDateTime;
        this.eventColor = eventColor;
        this.organizerResponse = new HashMap<>();
        this.organizerResponse.putAll(organizerResponse);
        this.guestResponse = new HashMap<>();
        this.guestResponse.putAll(guestResponse);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getInitialDateTime() {
        return initialDateTime;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getFinalDateTime() {
        return finalDateTime;
    }

    public String getEventColor() {
        return eventColor;
    }

    public Map<EventResponseEnum, String> getOrganizerResponse() {
        return organizerResponse;
    }

    public Map<EventResponseEnum, List<String>> getGuestResponse() {
        return guestResponse;
    }
}
```

---- UPDATED ----

I save with this entity.
And fetch it normaly using query. It brings exactly the way I want.

```
@Document(collection = "event")
public class Event {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime initialDateTime;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime finalDateTime;
    private String eventColor;


    @DBRef
    private Map<EventResponseEnum, ApplicationUser> organizer;

    @DBRef
    private Set<EventUser> guests;

//GETTERS AND SETTERS
```

Comment: That's works normally no custom serialization need, add details about how you strote in database and fetch

Comment: I updated the question